# Connecting Arduino Uno to Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, arduino-leonardo

I have an RFID shield connected to my Arduino Uno, but I want it to be able to send keystrokes to the computer when I scan the correct card. I have the Uno set up correctly so that when the card is scanned and verified it would send a 1 to the Leonardo. But when I have tried to receive the data using I2C, Leonardo doesn't get it. What could I try next?

This is the master code or the code that is sending the information. (On the Arduino Uno)

```
// Include the required Wire library for I2C<br>#include 
int x = 0;
void setup() {
  // Start the I2C Bus as Master
  Wire.begin(); 
}
void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(9); // transmit to device #9
  Wire.write(x);              // sends x 
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
  x++; // Increment x
  if (x > 5) x = 0; // `reset x once it gets 6
  delay(500);
}
```

and this is the slave code (on the Leonardo)

```
// Include the required Wire library for I2C<br>#include <Wire.h>
int LED = 13;
int x = 0;
void setup() {
  // Define the LED pin as Output
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  // Start the I2C Bus as Slave on address 9
  Wire.begin(9); 
  // Attach a function to trigger when something is received.
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}
void receiveEvent(int bytes) {
  x = Wire.read();    // read one character from the I2C
}
void loop() {
  //If value received is 0 blink LED for 200 ms
  if (x == '0') {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
  //If value received is 3 blink LED for 400 ms
  if (x == '3') {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(400);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(400);
  }
}
```

Comment: `x` in slave code needs to be defined `volatile`, since the callback gets called from an ISR. Have you tried with the I2C scan example, if the Uno actually finds the Leonardo? Also you could print the return value of `Wire.endTransmission()`. A successfull transmission is marked by a return value of zero. If not successfull, the return value is an error code. Please check the error code, it might show the problem. Have you pullup resistors on both I2C lines?

Comment: @chrisl I will try the `Wire.endTransmisson()`. But how do I define `x` as `volatile`?

Comment: With the keyword `volatile`. You can google how to use it. When you can confirm, that it solved your problem, I will write an answer, explaining that.